# Evaluating the product containing the reciprocals of all primes $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}{p_k}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, pi, infinite-product

How to compute the following product:

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}{p_k}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{7}\right)\dots$$

where $p_k$ is the $k^\text{th}$ prime number?

***My Observation, but NOT SURE:***

Using $k=1$ to $k=18$, the product is almost $0.578282825\dots$ and that value is

$$\frac{\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac{\pi}{6}}{2}=\frac{11\pi}{60}\approx0.575958653\dots$$

> So, is the product really tends to $\frac{11\pi}{60}$?

Any help/hint will be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Why would you think this product has a closed form?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(1%2B(-1)%5Ek%2Fprime(k))+for+k%3D1+to100

Comment: If you take the logarithm of the product, you get a sum of logarithms, which satisfies the hypotheses of the alternating series test.  Therefore [the product of the first 30 terms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(1%2B(-1)%5Ek%2Fprime(k))+for+k%3D1+to+30)  exceeds the final answer, but this is $.575671$ already comfortably less than ${11\pi\over60}$

Comment: This product doesn't have a closed-form because alternating the sign depending on the parity of the index of the prime doesn't have any arithmetical meaning (in particular in term of $\zeta(s)$ and other L-functions)

Answer (score 0):

*Just to give a few numbers.*

Let us consider the partial products
$$P_n=\prod _{k=1}^{10^n} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}{p_k}\right)$$ Computed exactly, here are the results (in decimal values)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 1 & 0.5849897151924156997471733 \\
 2 & 0.5738797348557373537954953 \\
 3 & 0.5733032174061992771374417 \\
 4 & 0.5732660657801225326295239 \\
 5 & 0.5732633085315702175401998 \\
 6 & 0.5732630922693932644226413
\end{array}
\right)$$